# Android hide navigation bar in Spinner dropdown mode

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-immersive

I was able to set Immersive mode in my app that properly hides navigation and status bars in almost every case. The only exclusion I found so far is, that when I tap on a `Spinner` component that has `android:spinnerMode="dropdown"`, the navigation bar still comes up. It disappears after I select an item from the dropdown, but I want it to not show up at all. Is there a way I could do this?